# return a generic function with specified type

Tags: c++, class, templates, generics

What if I have a generic class with type T and I have a function which returns with T. and I want my function to return a specific string if the typeid(T) == typedef(string)?

```
template<class T>
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1();
    ~Class1();
    T func();
};


template <class T>
T Class1<T>::func()
{
    string d = "T = string";
    if (typeid(string) == typeid(T))
        return (T)d; <-- here I got the problem
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do at all? How you use this code? What's the "problem"/error?

Comment: Explicit specialization.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "generic class". There are only "class templates". This misunderstanding seems to be at the root of a lot of beginner confusion.

Comment: yes, there is such a thing, but [in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference between the phrase "generic class" and "class templates"?

Comment: @DarlekSupreme In C++, there are only *class templates*. They are not types (or classes) themselves, but blueprints ("templates") to create classes. As Stephan T. Lavavej put it: "You can't eat a cookie-cutter, they're made out of metal. But you can use them to make cookies, and cookies are delicious." Generic classes are constructs of other programming languages such as C# and Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of explicit specialization of a member function of a class template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T>
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1() {}
    ~Class1() {}
    T func();
};


template <class T>
T Class1<T>::func()
{
    std::cout << "non-specialized version\n";
    return T();
}

template<>
std::string Class1<std::string>::func()
{
    std::cout << "string version\n";
    return "woot";
}

int main()
{
    Class1<int>().func();
    Class1<std::string>().func();
}
```